# addRole is not a function

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I am creating a Discord Bot.
I am trying create a Mute command, but I always get the same error.

[image]

What went wrong?

Background information:

- Discord.js version: `12.0.0-dev`
- Klasa with version `0.5.0-dev` is used

Code:

```
const { Command } = require('klasa');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = class extends Command {

    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args, { description: 'Mute an user.' })
    }

    async run(msg, args) {
        if(!msg.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MEMBERS")) return msg.channel.send("You can't use this command.");

        let MuteUser = msg.guild.member(msg.mentions.users.first() || msg.guild.members.get(args[0]))
        if(!MuteUser) return msg.channel.send("Can't find user!");

        let MuteReason = msg.content.split(" ").slice(2).join(" ");

        let MuteRole = msg.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "Spammer");
        if(!MuteRole) return msg.channel.send("Can't find the Spammer role!");

        let MuteChannel = msg.guild.channels.find(guild => guild.name === 'bot-logs');
        if(!MuteChannel) return msg.channel.send("Can't find the #bot-logs channel.");

        if(MuteUser.roles.has(MuteRole)) return msg.channel.send("That user is already muted!.");

        MuteUser.addRole(MuteRole.id);

        return MuteChannel.send(new MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor("Mute"|| 'Unknown', "http://wolfdevelopment.cf/BotSymbols/info.png")
            .setColor("#ff0000")
            .addField("Muted User", `${MuteUser}`)
            .addField("Muted By", `<@${msg.author.id}>`)
            .addField("Muted In", `${msg.channel}`)
            .addField("Time", `${msg.createdAt}`)
            .addField("Reason", `${MuteReason}`));
    }
}
```

I have checked that `MuteUser` is a person in this line:

```
    if(!MuteUser) return msg.channel.send("Can't find user!");
```

So it must be a person. Why doesn't it have an `addRole` function?

Comment: Have you checked the type of MuteUser and what methods are available?

Comment: The only way to give a person a role is .addRole()

Comment: What if some object that is not a person is assigned to MuteUser? Are you sure it is a person?

Comment: When I add msg.channel.send(`MuteUser = ${MuteUser}`) is MuteUser a person. http://prntscr.com/lpo5r3

Comment: I can't interpret your sentence. Please phrase it in a better way.

Comment: When I do this:
http://prntscr.com/lpo6n6
Is this the output:
http://prntscr.com/lpo5r3

Comment: Let me tell you once more: In `let MuteUser = ...`, you may have assigned, for example, a string, which is not a person, to it.

Comment: MuteUser is a person because when it isn't a person it gives this error: http://prntscr.com/lpo7c1
When it isn't a person it gives that error so MuteUser is a person...

Comment: `"@testUser-Discord"` is a string.
`!"@testUser-Discord"` returns `false`.
You should check the type of `MuteUser`.

Comment: But that is the way that Discord.js works... Everyone does it that way...
Every video I have seen uses that...

Comment: Blindly copying others without knowing how the code works leads to eventual failure.

Comment: I changed the code so it would work for me...

Comment: If it is working then you wouldn't post this question, would you?

Comment: I changed the code so it WOULD WORK for me... But it doesn't work... That is the problem...

Comment: Then you should try every method to see where the problem lies. `MuteUser` definitely doesn't have an `addRole` method. Therefore, my reasonable guess is that it is not a person. Got it?

Comment: But it is an person... Do you even know how Discord.js works?!

Comment: You checked if it is not a "falsy type" (read the MDN docs). You didn't check if it is a person. A string, for example, would pass through.

Comment: You didn't even try to print out the contents of `MuteUser`. Why are you so sure?

Comment: Do you even know how Discord.js works?!

Comment: Do you even know how to debug JavaScript?!

Comment: Dude, if you don't know how Discord.js and klasa work, then you can't help me with this problem!

Comment: Dude, if you don't try debugging, then you can't fix any bugs!

Comment: Ok, tell me what I need to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to look at this from another viewpoint and searched the Discord.js documentation for some more information. Sure enough, something is found:

I assume your call to `msg.guild.member` would result in a `GuildMember` because that is what the name implies.

Stable (Presumably 11.x): https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember
[image: Documentation]

Note that `addRole` is the first item below Methods.

Now, switching to master (aka Development branch - where you got 12.0.0-dev from)...
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/GuildMember

[image: Documentation]

`addRole` isn't there anymore.

Clicking the type of `roles`...
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/GuildMemberRoleStore
[image: Documentation]
`add` is the first method.

You can probably replace `MuteUser.addRole` with `MuteUser.roles.add`.

Note: This does not invalidate any of my words in the comments because you didn't provide enough information in the question itself on what type `MuteUser` is when the error was thrown.

Note 2: This took one Google search only. How much work did you even put into research?

Answer (score 0):

User don't have addRole : https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User
But [GuildMembers](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=addRole) does.

Are you trying to cast to a member in the line where you defined "let MuteUser" ? It could be normal that it does not have the addRole methods if it' a user.

Comment: That isn't `User` because of the call to `msg.guild.member` which I assume would return `GuildMember` instead.

Answer (score 0):

First: **users don't have a role. Only members have roles.**

**Users** are a discord user = a real life person (or a bot)

A **Member** object is a user "attached" to a server. So a member can have roles, because you only have roles within a specific server.

I tried `someMember.addRole(someRole)` too, and got the same `addRole is not a function`, error message.

Just try `someMember.roles.add(someRole)` and **it works!!!**

Providing I have:

1. guildID: the server ID
2. userID: the user ID
3. roleID: the role ID
4. memberID: NO !!! haha, got you!!! Members don't have IDs on Discord. A member is defined by a guildID and a userID, but it does not have an ID of it's own.

So, if I want to add a role to a member, here is what I do:

```
// get the guild
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildID);
if (! guild) return console.error("404: guild with ID", guildID, "not found");

// get the member
const member = guild.members.cache.get(userID);
if (! member) return console.error("404: user with ID", userID, "not found in guild", guild.name);

// we check our bot has role management permission
if (! guild.me.hasPermission('MANAGE_ROLES'))
    return console.error("I don't have the right to manage roles !!!  :-( ");

// get the role
const role = guild.roles.cache.get(roleID);
if (! role) return console.error("404: role with ID", roleID, "not found in guild", guild.name);

// add role to member
member.roles.add(role)
   .then(function() {
        console.log("role", role.name, "added to", member.user.name, "on server", guild.name);
        // do your stuff
   })
   .catch(function(err) {
        console.error("could not assign role", role.name,
            "to", member.user.name,
            "on server", guild.name,
            "because", error.message);
        // cry
   });
```

If that does not work:

1. Check that the highest role of the member is less powerfull than the highest role of your bot
2. Check that the role your bot is trying to add, is less powerfull than the highest role of your bot
3. And also: in the role configuration page of your server configuration, in the role list, **make sure the role you are trying to attribute, is listed under the role of your bot** (you can drag the roles to re-order them). (that one took me hours to figure out !!!)